# Predict magnitude from angle in linear regression

Tags: circular-statistics

I have some data where I want to see if the magnitude of an effect depends on the direction. (Analogous to asking if wind speed depends on wind direction, for example.) In the `circular` package there is `lm.circular` which allows doing regression using circular data. However, it only allows the independent variable to be 'linear' (i.e. non-circular), while what I need is the dependent variable to be linear.

I've seen one answer on Cross Validated that basically suggests to look at some cardinal directions. This could work - or I could use some bootstrapping / confidence intervals approach, but I was wondering if there is an existing test for this type of problem.

Comment: Your dependent variable is linear, while independent variables are circular?

Comment: Yes. I started to write a detailed description, but it just distracts from the question. In the end I measure the dependent variable in four different ways (that I want to compare). There is one direction where the largest effects should be found, but it might be shifted a bit in one direction in two of the methods and in the other direction in the other two. That should be tested. What I can't see is if the effect seems to fall of more or less quickly when measured in the different methods, but perhaps I should look at that too.

Comment: It's possible that the discussion in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60500/how-to-find-a-good-fit-for-semi-sinusoidal-model-in-r/60504#60504) (but presumably only with a single cycle, and possibly with several of the higher harmonics described there) might be of some help for your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, we want to predict a linear dependent variable from circular independent variables. There are several ways to approach this. The main thing to check is whether the relation between your dependent variable (let's say $Y$) and the circular predictor (say $\theta$) has a sinusoidal shape. This is often the case, but not necessarily. Below is an example of data of this shape.

```
th  <- rnorm(100, 1, 4) %% (2*pi)
err <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 0.8)
icp <- 10

bc <- 2
bs <- 3

y   <- icp + bc * cos(th) + bs * sin(th) + err

plot(th, y)
```

[image: Sinusoidal relationship between $\theta$ and $Y$.]

If the data does have this shape, roughly, a good simple model for the data is then given by splitting the circular predictor $\theta$ up in a sine and a cosine component, and running a regular linear regression on these two components, in this case by:

```
lm(y ~ cos(th) + sin(th))

>Call:
>lm(formula = y ~ cos(th) + sin(th))
>
>Coefficients:
>(Intercept)      cos(th)      sin(th)  
>      10.12         2.04         2.95
```

Of course, this can be done for multiple predictors as well. A good introduction on this may be found in Pewsey, Neuhauser & Ruxton (2013), Circular Statistics in R.

As mentioned before, we may add terms as in a Fourier regression, but this can only be recommended if the relationship structurally exhibits very different forms, because higher-order Fourier regression introduces, IIRC, a large number of difficult to interpret parameters.

Comment: Won't those 'cos(th)' and 'sin(th)' be highly correlated? (multicollinearity problem)
How can we solve this problem?

Comment: Multicollinearity is generally a problem with interpreting coefficients, not with estimating a model. Indeed, here we should not interpret these coefficients directly, as they are arbitrary (you can get different values for the coefficients if you take a different starting point on the circle).

Answer (score 2):

According to the title of your question, you want the linear regression.  There is no linear function from circular argument (except the function $ f(x)=0 $ ).  Therefore, you should use non-linear functions.  I recommend to replace each circular variables $x$ by two variables $\sin x $ and $\cos x$ and use both for linear regression.

Comment: I agree. This problem should yield to a centuries-old method known variously as Fourier, trigonometric or periodic regression. But you may need more than one pair of sine and cosine terms.