# GLMs must be 'linear in the parameters'

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear, parameterization

I am experiencing some cognitive dissonance about what 'linear in the parameters' means. For example, [here](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/heather_turner/glmCourse_001.pdf) and [here](https://www.acted.co.uk/forums/index.php?threads/generalized-linear-models-glms-linear-in-the-parameters.11917/).

For example, my understanding is $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1\beta_2x_1 + \exp(\beta_3)(x_2)^2 + \epsilon$ is not linear in the parameters, because it has two parameter  variables multiplied together (namely ${\beta_1, \beta_2}$).

If $\beta_1$ (say) was replaced with $\gamma_1$, a constant, it would be.

Appreciate if someone could clarify this point.

Comment: While you Are correct the function is not linear in the parameters, it can be made so with a log transformation

Comment: @Repmat How so? How will log transformation help here?

Comment: I don't see that **anything**, linear or nonlinear, will make $\beta_1, \beta_2$ separately estimable here. More positively, watch that GLM in different contexts means general linear models and generalized linear models, which overlap but are by no means identical classes.

Comment: Removing the product and the exp

Comment: OK, so you are reparameterising. That's not transformation (of variables), which was what I was inferring.

Comment: @Repmat What are you taking the log of, exactly? I don't see how that works.

Comment: @Nickcox exactly what I meant. But I suppose that $\beta_1$ would not be identified. I see the comment is unclear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example model can be reëxpressed to be linear in the parameters $\alpha=\beta_1\beta_2$ & $\zeta=\exp\beta_3$:

$$g(\operatorname{E} Y) = \beta_0 + \alpha x_1 + \zeta x_2^2$$

(Clearly $\beta_1$ & $\beta_2$ aren't separately estimable; a non-linear model wouldn't help there. And note that $\hat\zeta$ must be constrained to be positive.) Some models can't be so reëxpressed:

$$g(\operatorname{E} Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + x_2^{\beta_2}$$

Some can be though it's not obvious at first: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/60504/17230.

There's a very thorough discussion of different meanings of "linear" at [How to tell the difference between linear and non-linear regression models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148638/17230).

Comment: The reëxpression loses the information that $\zeta$ is constrained to be positive.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala: Good point - I'll note that.

Answer (score 5):

Linear in the parameters means that you can write your prediction as

$$\beta_0+\sum_{j=1}^px_{ij}\beta_j $$

For some definition of $x_{ij} $.  But these x's need not be linear functions of your data.  For example, ploynomial fitting of a time series has $x_{ij}=t_i^j $ where $t_i $ is the time associated with data point $i $.  The prediction is a non linear function of time, but it is linear in the betas.

**UPDATE**

In response to the comment, the answer is "sort of".  If $\beta_2$ was constant, then the predictor is linear in $\beta_0,\beta_1,\exp (\beta_3) $.  It is not linear in $\beta_3$, but a transformation of $\beta_3$.  In terms of least squares estimates it doesn't make much difference here.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. Perhaps my question isn't clarified by including a transformation of the x's. I am asking about the beta's (parameters), not transforms of x's. Perhaps if you could comment on my specific example above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better for you to understand the three components of the GLM. Esp, you need understand how link function is defined.

You can refer to the page 7 in the slides below. 'linear in the parameters' is true after being transformed by the link function.

[enter link description here](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/SPIDA/GLMs-notes.pdf)

Comment: While crucial in general, links don't seem pertinent to this thread.

Comment: Parameters are linear even before transformation.