# encoding categorical time series data with missing value

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, missing-data, normalization, keras

I am trying to pre-process (encode / normalize / standardize) my time series data where values are categorical and there exist, two types of `nan` values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t1': ['a', 'a', np.nan],
                   't2': ['b', np.nan, 'b'],
                   't3': ['b', 'a', np.nan],
                   't4': ['c', 'c', np.nan]}, index=['u1', 'u2', 'u3'])
df
```

[image]

where rows are users and columns are time where users have done a set of activities, e.g. `a`, `b` or `c`

Here we have **two types** of nan values

1. `u2` at time 2 or `u3` after `t2` - means the `u2` was inactive
2. `u3` at time 1 - this user didn't existed - he has joined from `t2`

Does it really matter there are two different types of `nan` ? anyway, my goal is to use **keras** to build a sequence 2 sequence model. However, I am not sure about the processioning steps. Is there any need to normalize and / or standardize this data ?

I read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570199/multivariate-lstm-with-missing-values),

> So you can assign zero to NaN elements, considering that zero is not
>   used in your data (you can normalize the data to a range, say [1,2],
>   and then assign zero to NaN elements; or alternatively, you can
>   normalize all the values to be in range [0,1] and then use -1 instead
>   of zero to replace NaN elements.)

I wonder given the above answer, what is the best way to normalize and standardize the data.

Based on my limited knowledge, I believe normalization in categorical setup doesn't make sense and approaches like one-hot-encoders are recommended.

For example one can do

```
pd.get_dummies(df,dummy_na=True)
```

[image: e]

but I am not sure if this is the most recommended way.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). Then people will be able to work with your data. Beyond that, I'm not very familiar with this (time-series, etc.), I think you're right that normalization doesn't make sense here, but someone else should be able to provide a more authoritative answer.

Comment: Since all of your NaN values have meaning they are not missing values. So you could pre process your data and replace NaNs that mean "user does not exist" with one kind of token and "user was inactive" with another.