# How do I interpret the sine and cosine terms in a linear-circular regression?

Tags: circular-statistics

When using a circular variable as a predictor (X) in a linear regression, the consensus seems to be to split the variable into sine and cosine terms.

e.g.  Y ~ cos(X) + sin(X) + etc

This creates two parameters that represent a single variable.

My question is: How would one interpret the effect of X on Y now that there are two parameters?

Comment: See the discussion here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/60504/805 . Things to pay attention to in the answer there: (1) how to convert the coefficients into amplitude and phase-offset;  (2) the importance of the choice of *period* (which you seem to ignore); and (3) the possibility of fitting additional harmonics.